# Failed to resolve: library

Tags: android, gradle

I want to use this library

```
implementation('com.ubudu.beacon:ubudu-ble-scanner-sdk:1.6.2@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

But I can't get it I don't know why, and when I access the link it works fine.

http://nexus.ubudu.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/com/ubudu/beacon/ubudu-ble-scanner-sdk/1.6.2/

This is my gradle file of the project :

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to add

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://nexus.ubudu.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/'}
}
```

in your **`build.gradle`**.

Comment: This is it Thanks a lot you save my time :)

Comment: you're welcome :) feel free to accept this answer by clicking ✓

Answer (score 1):

add this line to your Root level `build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://nexus.ubudu.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/' }
    }
}
```